# ASP.NET MVC 5 change login to authenticate via webservice call

Tags: c#, web-services, authentication, asp.net-mvc-5

I'm creating my first ASP.NET MVC website and am trying to use the template created by Visual Studio 2013.  My application does not directly access the database to authenticate and all other db calls.  Everything is done via a call to a legacy SOAP web service.  Also, the login uses username (instead of email) and I think I've done that change correctly.

I tried to override PasswordSigninAsync in ApplicationSigninManager to call my web service and return the appropriate result like so:

```
        public override Task<SignInStatus> PasswordSignInAsync(string userName, string password, bool isPersistent, bool shouldLockout)
    {

        ws.AppsWS webservice = new ws.AppsWS();
        System.Text.StringBuilder sb = new System.Text.StringBuilder();
        sb.Append("<Parameters><UserName>");
        sb.Append(userName);
        sb.Append("</UserName><Password>");
        sb.Append(password);
        sb.Append("<Password></Parameters>");

        return base.PasswordSignInAsync(userName, password, isPersistent, shouldLockout).ContinueWith(signInStatus =>
        {
            if (signInStatus.Result == SignInStatus.Failure)
            {

                var wsuser = new UserModel();

                var wsresult = webservice.CallAuthenticate(sb.ToString());
                if (wsresult.status.isSuccess)
                {
                    var thisRow = wsresult.dataTable.Rows[0];
                    wsuser.IsAuthenticated = Convert.ToBoolean(thisRow["Authenticated"]);
                    wsuser.UserId= thisRow["UserId"].ToString();
                    wsuser.FirstName = thisRow["FirstName"].ToString();
                    wsuser.LastName = thisRow["LastName"].ToString();
                    wsuser.Email = thisRow["Email"].ToString();
                    if (wsuser.IsAuthenticated)
                    {
                        return SignInStatus.Success;
                    }
                    else
                        return SignInStatus.Failure;

                }
                else
                    return SignInStatus.Failure;
            }

            return signInStatus.Result;
        });
```

Then on the calling function, it gets SigninStatus.Success for a valid username and password parameter.

```
        public async Task<ActionResult> Login(LoginViewModel model, string returnUrl)
    {
        if (!ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            return View(model);
        }


        // This doesn't count login failures towards account lockout
        // To enable password failures to trigger account lockout, change to shouldLockout: true
        var result = await SignInManager.PasswordSignInAsync(model.UserName, model.Password, model.RememberMe, shouldLockout: false);

        switch (result)
        {
            case SignInStatus.Success:
                return RedirectToLocal(returnUrl);
            case SignInStatus.LockedOut:
                return View("Lockout");
            case SignInStatus.RequiresVerification:
                return RedirectToAction("SendCode", new { ReturnUrl = returnUrl, RememberMe = model.RememberMe });
            case SignInStatus.Failure:
            default:
                ModelState.AddModelError("", "Invalid login attempt.");
                return View(model);
        }
    }
```

but in the _LoginPartial.cshtml:

```
@using Microsoft.AspNet.Identity
```

@if (Request.IsAuthenticated || TempData["IsAuthenticated"] == "True")
{

Request.IsAuthenticated is false.  How can I make the IsAuthenticated to be True and persistent so that my application knows that the user is authenticated in subsequent requests?

Hoping that you guys can point me in the right direction on how to approach this issue.  Thanks.